# How to compile C Linux libraries for use in Windows?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, cygwin, mingw-w64

I have a C program written on linux that I would like to be able to run and develop on window. The program has a few external dependencies on posix/linux libraries so I'm guessing I would need to somehow compile those libraries under windows too. I'm quite new to the linux workflow, and no expert in C and it's compiler make up either. I know something like cygwin and/or msys2 and/or mingw-w64 might be what I need but I'm not really sure how to get it working in a way that would make sense for me.

My program looks like this (only relevant parts shown), and currently runs under my ubuntu linux VM:

```
// Build:
// gcc -o disc-identifier main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 libmirage libisofs-1`
//
// Run:
// disc-identifier test_image.nrg

#include <glib.h>
#include <mirage/mirage.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <libisofs.h>

...

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
     ...
}
```

My ideal goal is to be able to have this as a visual studio project that I can add to a solution and to be able to link the required dependencies (and compile) from within visual studio. I then want it to compile into a portable 32-bit x86 application (maybe with a few accompanying dll files), no bigger than a few MB. But from my understanding I would first need windows compatible versions of the used libraries (glib, libmirage, libisofs), which is where I am a bit lost as to how I would go about this.

Comment: one of your dependencies exist under cygwin https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libglib2.0-devel.html . The big question is how portable should be the program ? If you need a stand alone windows program, try mingw.

Comment: Yes I am aiming for a standalone program that'll run without any additional software installed (Though not opposed to packaging a relatively small dll with it). libmirage also requires glib to build along with a bunch of other dependencies (which is part of what makes this so difficult). Not really sure where to start with mingw from what I've read the libs are likely to need significant source code changes to compile properly, which I don't really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not an expert of cross-platform development but I already build a cross-platform game (made with Irrlicht) mostly developped on Linux.

Have you heard or maybe already build your project with CMake ?
If not, I really invite you to check this very powerfull tool that [CMake](https://cmake.org/overview/) is.

Without entering in the details, CMake is a tool for cross-platform development that take care of many things and deliver to you ready-to-use build solutions, including for examples: Makefiles and Visual Studio solution files.
With little setups, you should be able to generate a `.sln` file for Visual Studio already ready to build your project for you (or require additional setups such as paths or DLL).

Sorry in advance if I misunderstand you question or if I'm not thorough technically.
Please let me know if you want for me to expand my answer ;)

Comment: I get that, I'm more looking for specific details of how to use mingw-w64 and/or cygwin (not really sure which one I need) for my use case, which is building windows compatible versions of 3rd party linux libraries, for use in a windows based development flow. I'm not trying to create a cross platform project, but more trying to utilise some tools that are only available on linux on windows, in a very much windows focused program. Using linux here was never my aim, but libmirage was the only library that supported the functionality I needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right - if the libraries are not "header-only" you need a platform specific build. But this is really easy right now. For this purpose I can recommend [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).
It supports msbuild and cmake integration - really nice.

To install for example glib you only need to open a cmd in your vcpkg folder and enter

```
vcpkg install glib
```

Visual studio supports both "msbuild" and "cmake" very well. Another option is to add dependencies via "NuGet" directly in Visual Studio.
If you use those tools, you don't need to compile the libraries yourself.

But what you have to check is if all your libraries support Windows. If not you can develop with Visual Studio and need to debug with "Remote Debugging". The easiest way is to use Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL).

Comment: Well the libraries (libmirage, and libisofs) don't really support windows out of the box and were never developed with windows in mind and definitely aren't available on nuget (otherwise I would be using that). The problem with using WSL is that my program could then only run under the subsystem which isn't what I need. I need a standalone executable that can be run on any windows PC.

Comment: WSL is just like a VM (but without a VM). So you want a native Windows application. The libraries itself do not need to be so close to either Linux nor Windows - so you could try to port them.
I have seem that for example fcntl.h is included. This header exists in Windows, too - but with different content...

In addition you could replace your library, perhaps there is already something which supports multiple platforms.

Comment: If you can find me another library that supports all the disk image formats that libmirage does then be my guest (trust me I've looked). I am asking for advice on how I would be able to essentially port this library to windows (without making major changes to it). Using WSL is not really any more useful than my existing Ubuntu virtual machine, where the code runs.